# Define locale WordPress uses with gettext functions?

Tags: localization

I'm trying to localize my plugin. I have two `.mo` files:

```
/lang/myplugin-es_ES.mo
/lang/myplugin-en_US.mo
```

The translation works but I don't understand how to change the language to use the `en_US` file instead of the `es_ES`. This is what I'm trying:

```
function define_locale($locale) {
    $subdomain = array_shift(explode(".",$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']));
    if($subdomain == "en")
        return 'en_US';
    else 
        return $locale;
}

// Define Locale
add_filter('locale','define_locale',10);
```

While `get_locale()` shows the locale is `en_US` my plugin still uses the `es_ES` file. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to add/change language flag in `wp-config.php` file

```
define ('WPLANG', 'en_GB');
```

REF: [Installing WordPress in Your Language](http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress_in_Your_Language)

Comment: I added a function and changed it in the wp-config based on the current url